# DIRTY_INDEX at merge

Tags: git, git-merge

I fetched some updates from upstream, merged, and got the following error message:

```
FAILED: DIRTY_INDEX [filename]
```

After a reset and another merge, I get this error:

```
FAILED: DIRTY_WORKTREE [another-filename]
```

All this is cryptic to me - what should I do now?

Comment: Please add what `git status` returns.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mention ed in "[Fun with keeping local changes around](http://gitster.livejournal.com/29060.html)":

> Linus often performs patch applications and merges in a dirty work tree with a clean index.
>
> - A dirty work tree is where you have changes that are not added to the index.
>     A work tree that is not dirty is a clean work tree.
> - A dirty index is where you have changes already added to it (in other words, "`git diff --cached`" will report some changes).
>     A clean index matches the `HEAD`.

Each time, `git status` can display what you need to do before being able to do a new merge.

[`git stash`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash), for instance, can save current work in progress in your working tree, and `git stash pop` will apply said work once the merge is done.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem. My suggestions for the solution would be:
 1. Before checking out the project from origin, make sure in the Project tab, the Build 
    Automatically option is turn off. And try merge with the other branch.